# Laravel using rest api source for both mobile and browser with authorization

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have an rest api that, depending on whether the user is authorized or not, issues different products `/api/products`. This api for a mobile application, I carry out authorization through a bearer token with `Sanctum`. To process requests from any users and, depending on whether there is a token or not, display goods.

My custom middleware for api

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ( $request->bearerToken() && Auth::guard('sanctum')->user() )
            Auth::setUser( Auth::guard('sanctum')->user() );

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Next, it took not only api but also a website that will use this api, which is intended for a mobile application.  Decided to use the usual php approach using vue components. Its `Breeze & Blade` with `Fortify` and Vue. As far as I understand, if the user is authorized through the  website, cookies with authorization come to him and they must be applied to Ajax requests.

My axios request from vue component to `/api/products`.
If the user is authorized through the website, then a cookie is applied and sent

```
const instance = axios.create({
    timeout: 2000,
   
    //My cookie included
    withCredentials: true,

    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true
       },

    //With token works. Middleware understands that the user is authorized
    //headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+'1|XedL48l1TU5KomRxix6xFrsm0v7jw5eTbHzfpoGC'}
  });

  instance
      .post("/api/products",
          {
            data: example_data,

          }, )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
      });
```

The problem is that the middleware does not understand the cookies that come with the axios request. Middleware can't figure out if I'm authorized or not through the cookies attached to requests. It understands only the token in header, it works with the token.The documentation says that the `Sanctum` middleware understands the cookies that are attached to the request, but I do not use the middleware sanctum. Is it possible to implement it somehow, so that the authorized user's cookies would be understood by my custom middleware and not just the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the one who answers your first questions.

You do not need to pass things like that when doing request from your front-end which is already authenticated through session.

All you have to is make sure to set with axios with credentials under
`resources/js/bootstrap.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'
window.axios = axios

window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Then you could simply call the end-point from vue template and the middleware would be able to idenfity authenticated request or not

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

async function getProducts() {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products`)
        console.log( data )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log( error.response.message ?? error.message )
    }
}

onMounted( () => {
    getProducts()
})

</script>
```

Just a side note, if you authenticating via API tokens, make sure to pass `Accept: application/json` on your header request

**EDIT**

your `app/Http/Kernel.php` should have this lines in `$middlewareGroups`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        .
        .
        .
    ],

    'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank you! But still doesn't work. The browser has debugging of all XHR requests, that vue sends. My request contains cookies `laravel_session`, `remember_web...` and `XSRF-TOKEN` if sent from an authorized user, but the middleware doesn't understand that the request came from an authorized user.I can’t understand why this is happening, because Laravel should understand session cookies

Comment: there is probably some misconfiguration with your app somewhere, could be in config `auth`, `session`, `cors`, `sanctum` or maybe kernel, trying checking the docs for spa auth https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication,

Comment: Additionally, my advise would be to isntall clean laravel project with breeze vue `php artisan breeze:install vue --ssr` and compare all the configs with your application config

Comment: This is a clean install, not spa, but the usual laravel `Breeze & Blade`, vue is connected as a component.  In the middleware itself, I can see the cookies `request()->cookie()` they are present, all those sent by axios. At the beginning, I thought it was the wrong axios job. I don’t understand why Laravel doesn’t want to use cookies for authorization

Comment: did you add `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` on `$middlewareGroups` `api` inside kernel?

Comment: if its a clean install, then looks like you haven't properly configured sanctum for API use on the front-end https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#installation

Comment: For some reason there was a commented out line that you said to check `\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` But still, nothing has changed. And i copy string from `web` middleware group to `api` section -> ` \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` Everything worked. I don’t know how it is in terms of security, because I change what I don’t understand, but it began to work, Laravel understands the cookies of an authorized user